# PostgreSQL - create a generated column for a column that already exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following raw `SQL` command that I am executing inside a `Django` migration file. I need to use raw `SQL` because `Django` does not support generated columns.

```
ALTER TABLE dockets_document ADD COLUMN search_vector tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(f_arr2text(content),'')), 'B') ||
    setweight(jsonb_to_tsvector('english', coalesce(tables), '["all"]'), 'C')
) STORED;
```

My `models.py` file has the following field:

```
search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)
```

This line triggers a migration that generates the column for me, then my custom migration applies the `SQL`. The custom migration fails because the column was already created (with a corresponding index) so `ADD COLUMN` returns the error `ERROR:  column "search_vector" of relation "dockets_document" already exists`. I tried using `ALTER COLUMN` in place of `ADD COLUMN` but it did not work (`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "tsvector"`).

I tried removing the field from the `models.py` file but then Django doesn't know that the field exists and won't allow me to query against the column. And it doesn't feel right to remove it either.

How can I convert the existing `null` column into a `GENERATED` column instead?

Comment: Maybe it will get easier to answer this if you can post your migration file - or at least _all_ parts of it that deal with your custom column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do RunSQL and add `state_operation`  as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunSQL)

> The state_operations argument allows you to supply operations that are
> equivalent to the SQL in terms of project state. For example, if you
> are manually creating a column, you should pass in a list containing
> an AddField operation here so that the autodetector still has an
> up-to-date state of the model

in manually generated [empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) migration